# Custom metadata retrieval fails in Winter '20

Tags: metadata-api, winter20

In Winter '20 sandbox, retrieval for custom metadata using wildcard is failing:

package.xml

```
<types>
    <members>*</​members>
    <name>CustomMetadata</name>
</types>
```

Th error was:

```
INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'some__sobject__mdt'
```

The same retrieve request works fine in Production because production has not been upgraded to Winter '20.

Anyone else experiences the same issue?

Further notes: I also found out that the **listMetadata API call is also failing for Custom Metadata**. So there is no way for us now to retrieve the list of Custom Metadata in the org. Seems to be quite a major bug.

Comment: confirmed its a bug ! We are having the same experience .

Comment: thanks Mohith, I can't find the known issue listed by Salesforce. Any ideas where it is ? If not, how can I report this ?

by the way, how are you guys getting around this ?

Comment: Simple just have to add everything in the package.xml explicitly and not use * .I have asked the PM on Twitter so will update as I hear back

Comment: cool. I noticed that the listMetadata api call is also failing. we have automated job that capture all custom metadata types so we're not going to be able to list them since they will be missed out in the future.

Comment: For now you I guess only option is to hard code and hope it gets fixed soon

Answer (score 1):

I've seen reports that the Salesforce engineering team are onto this.

If you are raising a support case it can reference the internal W-6597330 bug number.

Related: [The metadata retrieve operation failed: INVALID_TYPE: sObject when adding custom metadata to manifest](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/180)